# Where is serialized user profile returned from passport.js strategy is stored

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a NodeJS/Express/Passport App and no database is used.
Where is serialized user profile returned from passport.js strategy is stored?

Comment: If you mean how to get the user profile? You access it in the callback function. If you mean, where you should store it? Store it in the session.

Comment: What do you mean by store in the session? I am just using passport.use(session). Does it mean it is saving automatically? or should i call something explicitly to save it?